# Keytool usage with Runtime.getRuntime().exec() under Linux

Tags: java, command-line, keytool, runtime.exec

I'd like to call the java keytool during runtime execution providing dynamic arguments.
Here's what is working under Windows, but not under Linux (Ubuntu) same Java 1.6.0:

```
File f = new File("mykey.jks");
StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
command.append(System.getProperty("java.home")
            + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "bin"
            + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "keytool");
command.append(" -genkey");
command.append(" -dname \"cn=foo,ou=bar,o=company,c=CH\"");
command.append(" -alias myProduct");
command.append(" -keypass " + "testtest");
command.append(" -keystore " + f.getAbsolutePath());
command.append(" -storepass " + "testtest");
command.append(" -validity " + 3650);
final Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString());

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    pr.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

int exitVal = -1;
try {
    exitVal = pr.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // handle
}
```

The Output under Linux is

> keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keyword ""CN"

Running the command in the Linux command line (not starting in java), the code works. What am I doing wrong and how would the `String[]` look like when using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[]) instead

Then you dont have to worry about escaping each argument which you are not doing here

```
String args [] = {arg1, arg2, "-dname", "dNameArguments"};
```

Comment: I tried using the String[]-notation, but didn't get it work. How do I have to arrange the arguments (especially the -dname "...." argument)?

Comment: Thanks @Bengt, it worked fine! I always tried with String args [] = {arg1, arg2, "-dname dNameArguments"};