# Use keytool with Runtime.getRuntime().exec() under Linux

Tags: java, runtime.exec, keytool

I'd like to create a self-signed certificate by invoking keytool in my java script. Here is a simplified version of my code which includes the problem I have:

```
    public class Tester {
        public static void main(String[] args) {   
            String[] cmd = {   
                "/bin/sh",  
                "-c",  
                "keytool",  
                "-genkey",   
                "-dname",  
                "\"C=US,CN=CU,L=ABC,O=ABC_Univ,OU=ABC_Pro\"",  
                "-keysize",  
                "1024",  
                "-alias",  
                "testkeypairs",
                "-keyalg",  
                "RSA",  
                "-sigalg",   
                "SHA1withRSA",  
                "-keystore",     
                "testkeystore",  
                "-storepass",  
                "abcdef",  
                "-keypass",  
                "abcdef"  
            }    
            Process testProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);  
}
```

There is no error when I ran it. But it did not give me the keystore. My questions are:

1. The certificate generated by keytool is not considered as the "subprocess's output" which needs to be fed to the parent process using `getinputstream()`, is it?
2. If it is, I also tried the `getinputstream()` thing as discussed in the following post,

[Keytool usage with Runtime.getRuntime().exec() under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308148/keytool-usage-with-runtime-getruntime-exec-under-linux)

the program just got stuck and seems to never stop.

3. Is there any other ways to create self-signed certificate using java program?

I am a newbie in Java and English is not my first language. I hope I have expressed my question clearly.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying, but consider changing your tactic slightly:  instead of calling `exec` to call the keytool binary, try calling the Keystore creation code yourself, programatically.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312559/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-new-keystore

Comment: What I want is to create a self-signed certificate programmatically. I thought I can invoke keytool using Runtime.getRuntime.exec(), just like discussed the following post.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308148/keytool-usage-with-runtime-getruntime-exec-under-linux] I tried their method but couldn't get the certificate. @Hariprasad

Comment: @Gus Certificate signature is not possible with the standard java crypto API. You need to use a 3rd party library (e.g. BouncyCastle) to do that.

Comment: Is it possible the file is created, but in a different directory than you expected? Try specifying a full path for the -keystore parameter and see what happens.

Comment: You might need to call testProc.waitFor(); and also consume testProc.getInputStream(); and testProc.getErrorStream(); with something like while(stream.read()!=-1) {};

Comment: I've seen some posts about using BC. That's what I am going to try next.@Jcs

Comment: I did specify the full path in my code, just omitted here in the post.@erickson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a different approach again - since `keytool` is written in Java and it is delivered with the JDK, you can actually instantiate the keytool class directly, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22766095/991432). This approach will let you generate a self-signed certificate in the JKS file of your choice, but it won't give you programmatic access to the generated certificate.

Just watch out, under Java 7 you will need to do `new sun.security.tools.KeyTool()`, but under Java 8 the class has been moved and you will need to do `new sun.security.tools.keytool.Main`. And of course it only works for the Oracle JDK, the APIs are internal and not guaranteed to be present in any future Java version, etc., etc.